# Taskkill: Do I need to specify \t parameter multiple times?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, taskkill

I have 2 unwanted processes running: `foo.exe` and `bar.exe`, and both have child processes started by them.

I want to use `taskkill` to terminate all these processes (`foo.exe`, `bar.exe` and all child ones). Do I need to use `\t` parameter only once or do I need to use it multiple times? I.e., which version is correct:

a) `taskkill /f /im "foo.exe" /im "bar.exe" /t`

b) `taskkill /f /im "foo.exe" /t /im "bar.exe" /t`

?

Comment: As far as I remember, the `/T` option affects all listed/matching processes, but I cannot test at the moment; I will let you know as soon as I can...

Comment: @aschipfl Very interesting. Let me know! :)

Comment: Meanwhile I had the chance to test: `taskkill` applies the `/T` option for all processes, independent on the position of the switch (I tried with the Acrobat Reader DC process that runs some child processes and with the Windows Calculator, like `taskkill [/T] /PID <process_1> [/T] /PID <process_2> [/T]`, with `/T` put before the first, after the last, oir in between the processes, and with Acrobat Reader DC and Calculator on either position, so trying all possible combinations; each time all child processes of Acrobat Reader DC were terminated).

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you very much for this testing. It's a good addition for provided answer.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, the same is true for the `/F` option, it also affects all matching processes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a for loop will be more meaningful as you can add/remove imagenames as you please:

Using batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (foo.exe bar.exe) do taskkill /f /im "%%i" /t
```

From cmdline:

```
for %i in (foo.exe bar.exe) do taskkill /f /im "%i" /t
```

Comment: Thanks. As I understand, the correct version was "b", but you improved it?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. As you specify each image by itesefl, it is better to do the switching per image.